# Highstock marker points do not display on line series with grouped data

Tags: highcharts

Using `highstock v1.2.2` I am trying to set a few red marker points on a line series with approximately 8000 points.

However, the marker points are only displayed when the data is not being grouped.

When i increase the size of my navigator and the data is grouped, the marker points are no longer displayed.

I searched the `highstock api` and didn't find anything helpful. All i found was this issue: [Fixed issue with disappearing point markers after switching from non](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/7d562fa841d033153ca5e901a6660c379aa6318c), that was fixed about a year ago.

I also tried to increase the `turboThreshold` attribute with no luck. So how can i display marker points on a large data set when the points are grouped?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you set "a few" marker points. In that case, the markers will disappear when those individual points are grouped with other points, since the global option is that markers are disabled.

As an alternative, you should consider using flags for the points you want to emphasize. Or to make them look like regular point markers, you can even use a scatter series on top of the line series.

Comment: If the global option for markers was enabled, could the marker points still be displayed representing the points that are grouped? If so, how can i change the global option? I tried using a scatter series for markers, however when data is grouped in some cases the marker points on the scatter series appear to float because the y value of the grouped points became lower than what the scatter point was set to when the data was not grouped.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not currently possible, because there is no configuration option for the grouped point. You should try flags though - I believe those stick to the position of the grouped point.

Comment: ok yes, looks like they do stick to the grouped point. However, is there a way to use flags without any text in them? I want to make it look like a small red circle. The default text is 'A' though and always appears.

Comment: I was able to use style:{font-size:'0px'} on the series so the flags no longer displayed text in them.